# Trying to float <div> to the right in <header> -- not working

Tags: css, html

I'm coding this static homepage using HTML and CSS. I have the page on my server: http://blnr.org/fantasia

I have the 'header' div at a width of 100% within a pagewrap.

Within the 'header' div, I have two child 'left' and 'right' elements. In my CSS, I have the 'left' element floating left -- this is working correctly.

Okay, so I'm trying to float the 'right' element right, however, no CSS appears to be registering for this element on the page.

I'm not sure what the problem is. I've used this 'left' 'right' method before on a website I did and everything appears to work smoothly across browsers -- http://projectwaves.com

Please help!

Comment: Fixed, just forgot to correctly close a comment in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS file is invalid. Look at your code around these lines:

```css
#left hr {
    position: relative;
    margin: -1px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: thin dotted #E6E6E6;
    width: 230px;
}

/*                                          End Left
*/  --------------------------------------------------


/*  --------------------------------------------------
                                        Right Side */   

#right {
    float: right;
    width: 450px;
    height: 75px;
}
```

The line below the "End Left" is not part of the comment. You'll have to move it inside the comment like this:

```
/*                                          End Left
     -------------------------------------------------- */
```

Comment: Thank you! Totally missed that